# How to preserve user zoom level when update data in jquery amcharts v3

Tags: amcharts

In my site, I am using amcharts v3.
I update data for every 10 seconds, and whenever update data and redraw charts, it reset zoom level,
I want to maintain user zoom level.
If anyone ha experience, please help me thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`zoomOutOnDataUpdate`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amserialchart/#zoomOutOnDataUpdate_property) to false in your config to prevent the chart from zooming out on update.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  zoomOutOnDataUpdate: false,
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I have one more question. How can i show the number of points that in zoomed range whenever data updated?

Comment: There's the [`dataUpdated`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amserialchart/#dataUpdated_event) event, which fires after you update your data (validateData). From there you can use the chart's [`startIndex`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amserialchart/#startIndex_property) and [`endIndex`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amserialchart/#endIndex_property) properties to get the axis/data indexes visible and work from there.